# Keeping entries in a state store just for a defined time

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

Problem: I need to find out how sent a message in last e.g. 24 hours. I have following stream and state store for lookups.

```java
@SendTo(Bindings.MESSAGE_STORE)
@StreamListener(Bindings.MO)
public KStream<?, ?> groupBySender(KStream<String, Message> messages) {

     return  messages.selectKey((key,message) -> message.from)
                     .map((k,v) -> new KeyValue<>(k, v.sentAt.toString()))
                     .groupByKey()
                     .reduce((oldTimestamp, newTimestamp) -> newTimestamp,
                                Materialized.as(AggregatorApplication.MESSAGE_STORE))
                     .toStream();

}
```

it works fine

```
[
    "key=123 value=2019-06-21T13:29:05.509Z",
    "key=from value=2019-06-21T13:29:05.509Z",
]
```

so a look up loos like :

```
store.get(from);
```

but I would like to remove entries older then 24h automatically from to store, currently they will be persisted probable forever

Is there a better way how to do it? maybe some windowing operation or so?

Answer (score 0):

Atm, `KTables` (that are basically key-value stores) don't support a TTL (cf. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4212)

The current recommendation is to use a windowed-store if you want to expire data. You might want to use a custom `.transform()` instead of `windowedBy().reduce()` so, to get more flexibility. (cf. https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html)